# Relating parts of sentences

Tags: grammar, questions, relative-clauses

> エリナ：窓の外に見えるの皆シットル？　　
> Erina: Couldn't the rest of people look out of the window?

> タダシ：そうだろう　たぶん
> Tadashi: Yeah, maybe.

CONTEXT: After taking a flight and stopped in a station Tadashi is looking at a bunch of people in that station, then Erina ask him -what I guess- is something like "the rest of people did look out of the window?" then Tadashi answers "yeah, maybe", but I'm not sure how 皆 is related to シットル.

(rough translation attempt)

> タダシ：このディスク。。。やっぱ　このフライトレコーダーのじゃないかな
> Tadashi: This disk... It seems that it didn't belong to the black box.

> エリナ：うーん。。。　でも何でわざわざわかりにくい所へかくしてあるわけ？
> Erina: Yeah... but why they wanted to be this disk hard to read? did they have something to hide?

> タダシ：フライトレコーダーのだったとしたらさ　こう何か　とくべつなひこうきろくが　のこされてるとか！ (what does こう何か mean?)。。。　っていうのは？
> Tadashi: If this were a black box (...) this special register left here! Don't you think?

> エリナ：タダシにしては　まあまあの　せんね
> Erina: Being mad is not like you.

> タダシ：あのさ。。。！
> Tadashi: Sorry...!

CONTEXT: after looking inside a war robot, Tadashi and Erina founded a strange disk and an empty black box, then Tadashi says that that disk may not be for the black box, then Erina ask about the purpose then Tadashi gets mad. I can't relate the third sentence because of the こう何か.

Comment: シットル is a typo for シャトル or something, no? Can you check the original? It'd be quite strange the girl should use dialectal 知っとる here when she's speaking in Standard Japanese all through the conversation. Also the boy's response そうだろう たぶん wouldn't fit.  If it really meant "Do you know all the people out there?" it should be something like 窓の外に見える**人** 皆知ってる？

Comment: There is only one place that really sticks out if you consider her speaking dialectally, かくしてある -> かくしとる or かくしとう, but in my experience, coming from a region that uses this kind of dialect, it really is not that uncommon to mix a bit. But I agree that そうだろう たぶん wouldn't be the most natural response, about 人 I assumed it's just been omitted for whatever reason. It would be nice with a proper context though. Googling the text doesn't give any response, so I would think that OP has tried to transcribe it by listening.

Comment: @bjorn `There is only one place... ` No. 見えるの and まあまあの線ね are not dialectal, either. It's not まあまあ+のせん+ね but まあまあ+の+線+ね. If you don't know/understand the phrase 「まあまあの線(だ)」, I recommend you check the meaning/usage of 線 in the common expression 「いい線(を)行っている」https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/いい線いってる

Comment: @chocolate 知っとるが使われている九州弁の中には「見える」を「見ゆる」に変えている方言もありますが、標準語と同じく「見える」が使われている方言もありますよ （例えば博多弁、佐賀弁）。そして、方言のある地域から来たとしても、バラバラで方言と標準語を混ぜったりすることもよくあるので、完全な方言文書ではないとゆう事だけで方言だか書き間違いだかは決断できないと思います。「線を行っている」は初めて聞いたので、教えてくれてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

シットル is dialectal version of 知{し}っている and means to know. Translation is thus:

> 窓の外に見えるの 皆シットル？
>
> Do you know all the people out there?

If it were the する verb it would have been written しとる

じゃないかな means something like "I wonder if it can't be", it is thus not an actual negation of the sentence in this case.

> このディスク。。。 やっぱ　このフライトレコーダーのじゃないかな
>
> This disk, I wonder if it doesn't belong to this flight recorder? (note: depending on intonation, it could also mean what you are writing, but from context I would go with the positive version)

For the reply, you are misunderstanding it at several places:

> うーん。。。　でも何でわざわざわかりにくい所へかくしてあるわけ？

Let's split it up:
でも何で = but why

わざわざ = go through the trouble of

わかりにくい所へ = わかりにくい means difficult to know and modifies the noun 所, so difficult to know place

かくしてある = is hidden

わけ？ = nuances the question (in English I'm using "would" instead of "did" for the translation because of this)

> Yea... but why would they go through the trouble of hiding it in such a difficult to find spot?

.

> フライトレコーダー**の**だったとしたらさ　こう何か　とくべつなひこうきろくが　のこされてるとか！ (what does こう何か mean?) 。。。　っていうのは？

First of all, notice the の particle after the flight recorder, it is written in possessive form and refers to the disk. Thus the disk in the subject, not the flight recorder.

こう is just a filling word, similar to "like" in this case (it could also be that he is demonstrating something while speaking, and referring to that)

> If this belongs to the flight recorder, maybe it could be like a special flight recording or something!
>
> タダシにしては　まあまあ のせん ね

Here I think the sentence should be split like this instead. のせん should then once again be a dialectal verb form, from のせない, but I am not really sure exactly what is meant by this sentence.

Comment: 「まあまあのせん」は「まあまあの線」って意味でしょう？

Comment: Woah, the first and second seems to be really accurate, I didn't expect slang from シャトル because of "shuttle" word that was confusing, but in the third, I thought のこすmeant "to left behind", and in the four I wrote "not being mad" as a synonym of a literal "Way of Tadashi is being quiet (as opossed to the exasperation of the previous sentence)".